# GCP cloud shell disconnecting frequently

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I logged into Google cloud and cloud shell keeps on disconnecting . Not sure why it is. Internet is fine.
Error:
The connection to your Google Cloud Shell was lost.

Answer (score 0):

You could see the status of all the Google Cloud Components in the following web:

https://status.cloud.google.com/

If there is no issue in the web page, probably the problem could be related with your Internet Service Provider.

Comment: No, there is no problem with internet, as my other internet activity is going on without interrupt. I also enabled 'Enable Tmux' assuming that would solve my problem, but still it is disconnecting every once in every 5 min.